# How to limit the spawn object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add a limit in a spawn objects. I want to keep the spawn object to one. but it's not working at all.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour {

public Spawn04[] pest;
public GameObject plantPest;





void Start () {
}

[System.Obsolete]
void Update () {
if(plantPest.active)
{
    SpawnObjects();
}


}
void SpawnObjects()
{
    int i = Random.Range(0, 100);

    for(int j = 0; j < pest.Length; j++)
    {
        if(i >= pest[j].minProbabilityRange && i <= pest[j].maxProbabilityRange)
        {
            Instantiate(pest[j].spawnObject, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            break;
        }
        if(pest[j].pestCount >= pest[j].maxNumber)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
  }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Spawn04
{
public GameObject spawnObject;
public int minProbabilityRange = 0;
public int maxProbabilityRange = 0;
public int maxNumber = 1;
public int pestCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by limit? Your code seems to hint that you are looking for a probability to spawn.

Comment: yeah my spawn object have a probability. but i want to add a max number of spawn object.

Comment: Keep count of the current enemies spawned when instantiated and pass them a death callback. When the enemies die, decrement the count and spawn again.

Comment: Why is your `Update` marked as `[Obsolete]` ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a counter and a variable to controlling your max count. Just remember to decrement the counter after the object is despawned.

```
public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour {
    
    public Spawn04[] pest;
    public GameObject plantPest;
    
    public int maxPests = 10;          // ADDED
    private int pestsSpawned = 0;      // ADDED

    [System.Obsolete]
    void Update () {
        if(plantPest.active)
        {
            SpawnObjects();
        }
    }
    void SpawnObjects()
    {
        // NEW CHECK
        if (pestsSpawned < maxPests) {
            int i = Random.Range(0, 100);

            for(int j = 0; j < pest.Length; j++)
            {
                if(i >= pest[j].minProbabilityRange && i <= pest[j].maxProbabilityRange)
                {
                    Instantiate(pest[j].spawnObject, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                    pestsSpawned++;     // COUNT TRACKER
                    break;
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is using a static variable on the Spawn04 object as such:

```
public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour {
    
    public Spawn04[] pest;
    public GameObject plantPest;
    
    public int maxPests = 10;     // ADDED

    [System.Obsolete]
    void Update () {
        if(plantPest.active)
        {
            SpawnObjects();
        }
    }
    
    void SpawnObjects()
    {
        // NEW CHECK
        if (Spawn04.spawnCount <= maxPests) {
            int i = Random.Range(0, 100);

            for(int j = 0; j < pest.Length; j++)
            {
                if(i >= pest[j].minProbabilityRange && i <= pest[j].maxProbabilityRange)
                {
                    Instantiate(pest[j].spawnObject, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                    Spawn04.spawnCount++;     // COUNT TRACKER
                    break;
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
  
[System.Serializable]
public class Spawn04
{
    
    public GameObject spawnObject;
    public int minProbabilityRange = 0;
    public int maxProbabilityRange = 0;
    public static int spawnCount = 0;     // ADDED
}
```

Hope this gives some inspiration on how to address this issue.